# Coding at multiple locations?

Tags: php, git, operating-system, development-environment, vagrant

At the moment I am using poor method to work at home and at work to do web development.

I use Wamp for testing/development and then I upload to a production web server (Linux) via FTP.

If I continue with the project at home, I have to download the files from FTP.

What is good method to work on same projects at multiple locations?

Someone suggest me to learn Git and get Github private account. Also suggested to get Vagrant installed at work and home. Do I need to install Git in Vagrant VM or local machine?

Comment: Ok, have you looked into Git yet?

Comment: +1 for Git and Vagrant!

Comment: @ConnorPeet How did you work Git with Vagrant? Did you install Git on Vagrant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Learn git: http://try.github.io
- Create a Vagrant/VrtualBox VM by following the directions at https://puphpet.com

One of the tricks here is to put the Vagrant stuff you get from Puphpet directly in your project and then commit all of it to git. You'll then be able to check out the project in a new environment and, as long as Vagrant and VirtualBox are installed, you can run `vagrant up` and be working in about 5 mins.

Here's an example of how I'm doing just that to allow people to easily try out a library I've written: https://github.com/jeremykendall/query-auth-impl.

Enjoy! Your life as a developer is about to get a lot easier and a whole lot better.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Where did you install Git. On windows local machine or in Vagrant directly?

Comment: Install git on your local machine, both at work and at the house.  Github's help is *amazing* where installation and configuration are concerned: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git.  Git will be installed on the VM for you if you use the manifest you get from PuPHPet.

Answer (score 1):

Github or Bitbucket.  Git or Mercurial, and also Svn if it's just for yourself and you want an easier learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Any source control system would be ideal for this.

You don't want your *production server* to be the source of truth for the actual code.  Those two concerns should definitely be separated.  The production application is the *output* of the code, not the code itself.  For a language like PHP the two may be identical, but the concerns themselves should still be separated.  Indeed, for small systems the two services may even be hosted on the same server, but should still be logically separated.

The source control system maintains the changes made to the code over time, the production server is a snapshot of the current release version of the code.